# Python 3.6.2, using itemgetter from operator -> TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a sample dict:

```
sample = {1: 2, 3: 4, 4: 3, 2: 1, 0: 0}
```

**Objective:**

Get a sorted list of (key, value) pair on the keys.
It should look something like this:

```
[(0, 0), (1, 2), (2, 1), (3, 4), (4, 3)]
```

**I tried this:**

```
import operator as o   
lst1 = sorted(sample, key = o.itemgetter(0))
```

**Following is the error**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
    lst1 = sorted(sample, key = o.itemgetter(0))
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Not sure what am I missing.

Comment: Try `list(sample)` and see what you get…

Comment: The error message in your title doesn't match the error message in your question body.

Comment: @deceze: this is incorrect, `list(sample)` will return a list of `sample.keys()`

Comment: @FabienP ... agreed. list(sample) will return the list of keys

Comment: @FabienP Exactly my point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to sort the key-value pairs, sort the key-value pairs, not the dict:

```
sorted(sample.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(0))
#            ^^^^^^^^
```

(The key is somewhat superfluous for this case, but it doesn't hurt.)

Comment: Will try that. Thanks :)

Comment: As you said, `sorted(sample.items())` will achieve the same as it will sort `(k, v)` tuples on `sample.keys()`

Comment: sorted(list(sample.items()), key = o.itemgetter(0)) did give me the desired output.